# Convert Windows Application to Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows

I am having a Windows Application and I want to run it with WINDOWS SERVICE. I have created a WINDOWS SERVICE Application, now How would I integrate my WIN APP within this windows service application?

Comment: By putting your `Main()` logic inside `OnStart()` and making sure you return from there in time. If you want any more specific help, I'd suggest posting the relevant code and a specific question.

Comment: Do you have the code for the Windows Application or is it third-party?

Comment: @RonDeijkers Actually its kind of a medium sized Application, code is large.

Comment: Currently I am having a single Solution with a Windows Application & an Empty Windows Service. 2 Different Project in a single Solution

Comment: Please help me out, I am stucked here...

Comment: Well then the first thing to do is what CodeCaster suggested. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a common requirement and I suggest you to consider the following:
My code will be be using the following package  : [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/)

After :

```
nuget Install-Package Topshelf
```

In your start have something like the following :

```
    public static int Main()
    {
        var exitCode = HostFactory.Run
        (
            c =>
            {
                c.Service<Service>
                (
                    sc =>
                    {
                        sc.ConstructUsing(name => new Service());

                        sc.WhenStarted((service, hostControl) => service.Start(hostControl));

                        sc.WhenStopped((service, hostControl) => Service.Stop(hostControl));
                    }
                );

                c.SetServiceName("ServiceName");

                c.SetDisplayName("DisplayName");

                c.SetDescription("Description");

                c.EnablePauseAndContinue();

                c.EnableShutdown();

                c.StartAutomaticallyDelayed();

                c.RunAsLocalSystem();
            }
        );

        return (int)exitCode;
    }
```

And follow the configuration available in
[TopShelf configuration](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#simple-service)

We are using TopShelf in lots of our projects and it completely fulfills our needs.